# How to route to error page without leaving the current page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have running Angular 9 application and as per the correct implementation, if any unhandled exception occurs, I am routing to error page.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
   handleError(errorObj) {
      router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: { error: JSON.stringify(errorDetails) } })
   }
}
```

I am using ErrorHandler class and want to display error page as overlay , where in error page will be displayed on top of the current page and in background the current page should still be shown.

Comment: That sounds like you want to display a modal, instead of _route_ to a different url.

Comment: yeah, how can I do that..?

Comment: I'd suggest you search for _"Show a modal in Angular"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the dialog from Angular Material

Imports:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
```

Constructor:

```
constructor(
  private dialog: MatDialog,
) { }
```

Function to display the dialog:

```
error() {
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CustomErrorHandler, {
   width: '70%', // Make this as big as you want
   data: { error: this.errorType } //Put here the data you want to display one the error page. If you dont need it just delete the line and the ,
 });
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)